# MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 No longer working with IIS 7.5 and ASP Classic

Tags: dll, asp-classic

I maintain a legacy website written in asp classic that uses the MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 DLL heavily and today all of a sudden it is throwing an error advising it can’t find the specified DLL. I did a check and the DLL is there and is registered correctly on the server.

Does anyone know if this DLL is no longer supported in Windows?

Comment: The server is running Windows 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: It should still work.  Things you might want to check if you can, is the dll corrupted, does your website's IUSR account have the necessary permissions on the dll.  There should be a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version of msxml6.dll installed, but it's worth seeing if turning 32 bit applications on or off in the app pool makes any difference.  Version 3 of the dll should be present along with version 6, so something else to try is `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")`, leaving out the "6.0" so that you're not forcing your server to use a particular version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now resolved this (for now). The issue was with one of our API providers not the dll. Here was their response:

"We found a cipher that is not vulnerable and still supported on win 2012. Could you please test if you have an issue connecting using Win2008? We could leave it enabled for a longer period."

Enabling this cipher is what fixed the issue.